# how to use @Html.DropDownListFor with custom datatype

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I have following model & simple drop down in the view. I want to populate the customer name in the drop down. I tried following code but it did not work, can anybody what is wrong with this code.

**Model**

```
 public class customer
{

public int id { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
public string address { get; set; }

  }
```

//////////////////////////

```
    @{
   Layout = null;
   }

    @model IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.customer>

      <!DOCTYPE html>

        <html>
    <head>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
      <title>Index</title>
   </head>
         <body>
      <div>

 @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.name, new SelectList(Model,"id","name"));

        </div>
```

Comment: _"it did not work"_ - explain please.

Comment: I am getting this Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.customer>' does not contain a definition for 'name' and no extension method 'name' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.customer>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Your model is `IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.customer>` or a list of customers, yet with `@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.name)` you try to access one instance of `customer`.

Comment: Seems like you`re losed reference for MvcApplication1 namespace.

Comment: If I use @Html.DropDownList("name", new SelectList(Model, "id", "name")); then it works, not sure how to make DropDownListFor work ?

Comment: I am using the entity framework. In my initial post I modified the customer class for brevity, here is the complete code for customer class 
namespace MvcApplication1
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class customer
    {
        public customer()
        {
            this.orders = new HashSet<order>();
        }
    
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
    
        public virtual ICollection<order> orders { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: // <auto-generated>  namespace MvcApplication1
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class customer
    {
        public customer()
        {
            this.orders = new HashSet<order>();
        }
    
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
    
        public virtual ICollection<order> orders { get; set; }
    }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your attempt of doing this, you have made some basic mistakes. First try to understand what's going behind the scene in MVC and what those keywords mean.

you have defined

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.customer>
```

then you have the following code

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.name, new SelectList(Model,"id","name"));
```

here, your `m` denotes the @model which you have initialised as an `IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.customer>`. You are trying to access a property called name in IEnumerable (`m => m.name`) and `IEnumerable` doesn't have such property. if you want to access your model like that for some reason, your `@model` should be a Customer object. Then you can access it like `@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.name, new SelectList(Model,"id","name"));`

in a comment, you've said that this code `@Html.DropDownList("name", new SelectList(Model, "id", "name"));` works fine. Yes, it works because you are creating a new html select element with the Id `"name"` and it list anything that is in the `Model` as select options.

Okay, enough explanation.

This is the solution that I suggest for your problem.

In you controller action, implement the code flow as follows.

```
var dropdownDataList = //select your data from the database or any place as a list;

var dropdownOptions = dropdownDataList.Select(d => new {
    id = d.valueforid,
    name = d.valueforname
});

ViewBag.DropdownListOptions = new SelectList(dropdownOptions, "id", "name");

return View();
```

now in your view, do the following.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@model MvcApplication1.customer

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
       <title>Index</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.name, (SelectList)ViewBag.DropdownListOptions)
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

try to go through these articles in MSDN.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416514(v=vs.108).aspx

hope this helps.

Cheers,
Amila

Answer (score 2):

There are many samples on this exact question on Stack Overflow.  I have answered it many times before.

Use a view model to represent your data on the view, do not pass your domain object to the view.  A view model has on the properties that you need on the view, in this case I am only going to work with a drop down of your customers.

Your view model could look like this:

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
     public int CustomerId { get; set; }

     public IEnumerable<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

Your customer class:

```
public class Customer
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Your controller:

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
     private readonly ICustomerRepository customerRepository;

     public Customer(ICustomerRepository customerRepository)
     {
          this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
     }

     public ActionResult Create()
     {
          CustomerViewModel viewModel = new CustomerViewModel
          {
               Customers = customerRepository.GetAll()
          };

          return View(viewModel);
     }
}
```

Your view:

```
@model YourProject.ViewModels.Customers.CustomerViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(
     x => x.CustomerId,
     new SelectList(Model.Customers, "Id", "Name", Model.CustomerId),
     "-- Select --"
)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CustomerId)
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this
change your model to something like this

```
public class customer
{

public int id { get; set; }
public string SelectedName { get; set; }
 public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Names { get; set; }
public string address { get; set; }

  }
```

In controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Customer()
{
  var names=//collect names from database
  var model = new Customer
    {
       Names = names.Select(m=> new SelectListItem
         {
            value = m.whatever value you want to get(probably Id)
            text = m.name you want to display
         })
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and in view

```
@model MvcApplication1.customer
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedName, Model.Names)
```